# Show notification (); method not working, makes the app crash

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is the method for the show notification i cant get it to run so basically it will show a simple notification that the bluetooth has been disconnected. this method is in an activity file.

There is no error in the code the problem is i think the shownotification is not working for some reason it crashes when it is called

```
public static void showNotification(Context c){

    // define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
    Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity, NotificationHandler.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SettingsActivity, 0, intent, 0);

    // this is it, we'll build the notification!
    // in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0
    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(SettingsActivity)

        .setContentTitle("New Post!")
        .setContentText("Here's an awesome update for you!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setSound(soundUri)

        .addAction(R.drawable.logo, "View", pIntent)
        .addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)

        .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
    // myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);

}
```

And here is where i call the method shownotification(); where in on onBTDisconnect(); it will show the notification.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    String action = intent.getAction();
    SettingsActivity SA = new SettingsActivity();

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {

        isConnected = true;
        if(SettingsActivity.isRunning)
            SettingsActivity.onBTConnect();
    }
    else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) { 

        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isConnected = false; 

        if(SettingsActivity.isRunning)
            SettingsActivity.onBTDisconnect();
        SettingsActivity.showNotification(context);


    }else{

        //Handling of text messages received
        Bundle bundle= intent.getExtras();

        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
            if(isValidNumber(context,msg.getOriginatingAddress()))
                TextMessageManager.getInstance().addNewMessage(context, msg.getOriginatingAddress(),msg.getMessageBody());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mind showing the logcat error; and 1 question why arent you calling the notifcation codes in your receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Define notificationManager  globally (after extends Activity..  )   `NotificationManager notificationManager;`